# Service-to-service authentication using Azure Managed Service Identity & App Service Authentication?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I like the simplicity that MSI brings and it's awesome way to use e.g. Key Vault from Web App, but I haven't quite figured out how to use it to make service-to-service authentication simple. It should be possible, right?

For API App I need to enable App Service Authentication/Authorization.
For caller service enable Managed Service Identity.
I suppose that won't itself be enough (although it would be awesome!), but I'll probably need to forward credentials somehow using HttpClient? Any ideas? Or any other recommended (and SIMPLE) way to implement service-to-service authentication using AAD Service Principals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understanding correctly, you want to know how to access an API protected by Azure AD via MSI.

Generally, once enabled MSI for your Azure service (ie, Azure web app ) , An AD Enterprise App will be created at the same time , this app on behalf of your Azure service in your Azure AD.

For the API that you want to access , you should create an app role and assign the role to the AD Enterprise App which on behalf of your Azure service enabled with MSI. Once all processes have been done, you will be able to get the access token to access the API you want via the code below (this C# code should be run on your Azure service which enabled MSI ):

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
string apiToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("<API resource URI or API App ID>");
```

For more detail information you could refer to this [blog](https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions).

Comment: Do you know if I need to get a new token for each request I make to a protected API?
I'm trying to call an Azure AD protected API, and i need to obtain a token, but i'm unsure if I need to obtain the token once during startup and configure startup.cs to get the token when creating the httpClient? Struggling to find examples.